# Change visibility of symbol instance from inside another symbol's script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have a project in Flash Professional CS5 and ActionScript 3.

I have a movieclip symbol (referred herein as "background" with scripts on various keyframes inside of that symbol. I need to hide or show another symbol (referred herein as "object") sharing a stage with "background".

To put it another way, I need "object" to be hidden when "background" reaches a certain internal keyframe. However, as "object" and "background" are both children of the same stage, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On background`s timeline, put:

```
MovieClip(parent).getChildByName("object").visible = false;
```